# Are all microstates always equally probable?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy

The Gibbs entropy is given by:

$S_G = -k_B \sum P_i log(P_i)$,

where the summation runs over all possible microstates. I've seen one of the assumptions for statistical mechanics was that all microstates are equally likely. But then it seems to me that we would get the Boltzman form for entropy ($S_B = k_B log(\Omega)$) every single time, as the $log(P_i)$ term is constant, so its expectation is just itself, and $P_i$ will just be given by $\frac{1}{\Omega}$, where $\Omega$ is the total number of microstates available to the system.

So I have to conclude that all microstates are not equally probable, but this was one of the key assumptions I have seen in motivating the statistical definition of temperature. I'm unsure of how to reconcile this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
The temperature derivation mentioned above is as follows:

Consider 2 large thermodynamic systems, one with well defined energy $E_1 $ and the other with well defined energy $E_2$. Let $\Omega_1(E_1)$ be the number of microstates for the corresponding macrostate defined by having energy $E_1$. And likewise for $\Omega_2(E_2)$.

Then, **assuming all microstates are equally probable**, the system will most likely be found in the macrostate with the largest number of microstates, as the probability will be proportional to this number. The joint state will have $\Omega(E_1,E_2) = \Omega_1(E_1) \cdot \Omega_2(E_2)$ possible microstates for the two energies of the two systems. We therefore maximise this value to find the equilibrium state of the joint system:

$$\frac{d}{dE_1} \Omega(E_1,E_2) = 0$$
$$\frac{dln(\Omega_1)}{dE_1} = \frac{dln(\Omega_2)}{dE_2}$$

As thermal equilibrium is defined by having the same temperature, we identify this quantity with the temperature, such that:

$$\frac{1}{k_B T} =  \frac{dln(\Omega_i)}{dE_i}$$

And this is the familiar result for the statistical definition of temperature. I don't think it would be possible to arrive at the same result if we hadn't assumed all probabilities of microstates to be equal.

Comment: The essence of the MaxEnt principle (especially here in Stat. Mech) is to maximize the Gibbs-Shannon entropy under certain constraints. If you maximize it with no additional constraints other than normalization of the probability distribution, you get that all states are equal probable. Often we also fix certain averages, e.g. that of the energy, as a constraint. This yields various ensembles, e.g. the canonical one.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, I've seen this method be done with Lagrange multipliers and it makes sense mathematically to me. However, from what I've seen I thought the assumption of equal probabilities for all microstates was a postulate that was necessary in defining temperature; also that the whole justification for the statistical approach of purely looking at the number of different permutations of microstates to yield the same macrostate in order to find probabilities is built on this principle. Would this not break down?

Comment: I don't understand and I don't understand why you would need so to define temperature. In e.g. the canonical ensemble, temperature is well defined and not all states are equal probable.

Comment: Will attach an edit to the original post with the temperature derivation I've seen

Comment: I thought all microstates being equally probable was one of the assumptions of the canonical ensemble? Indeed the derivation for the Boltzmann distribution for energy in the canonical ensemble that I have seen uses this assumption to justify using the number of microstates per macrostate as the probability.

Comment: Your "derivation of temperature" assumes all the *microstates of the combined system* 1+2 have equal probability. This is the usual assumption for isolated systems with constant energy. Microstates of the subsystem 1 or of the subsystem 2 are not equally probable. In fact their probabilities are given by the Boltzmann distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if this is going in the direction you are asking for. You are saying that the stated formula $S=k_B \log(\Omega)$ will always be the outcome even for not equally probable states, am I right?

Let's see an example: $p_1=1/4, p_2=1/4$ and $p_3=1/2$

Inserted in the formula above: $S=-k_B[2\cdot (1/4\log(1/4))  + 1/2\log(1/2)]$
$=k_B/2[\log(4)+\log(2)]=k_B/2\log(8)= 3/2k_B\log(2)$

This is definitely not the samea as the blind calculation of having 3 states which are equally probable: $S=k_B\log(3)$

Comment: I agree completely with your math, I'm not saying that the Boltzmann formula will be the outcome for the not equally probable case, and, to my understanding, it's precisely this 'incorrectness' that motivates the Gibbs formulation, to allow us to define entropy outside the equally probable case. My question is more about when this can happen, and why it's allowed to happen when it seems like a fairly fundamental postulate in motivating a lot of the statistical arguments I've seen thus far in stat mech, including but not limited to, the temperature derivation shown in the original post.

Comment: Okay, now I understand. First of all, I think it is important to mention again (but it seems that you are quite aware of this), temperature can generally be derived as the change of the entropy of a system if we infinitesimally change the internal energy of it. (This is actually giving the inverse temperature) You can provide systems that even lead to a decrease of entropy and thus to a negative temperature. One example(not negative) might be Bekenstein entropy which is assumed to describe the entropy of black holes. Here we cannot even think about microstates but it is an entropy description.